# elfinder no url in inputfield

Tags: ckeditor, elfinder

I try to use Elfinder v2.1.20  with CKeditor v4.6.2 , but when wil add a image to the inpufield  , Elfinder open  the image in a popup window,
 but NO url add in the input field.

Someone can help me with this.

[test page](http://duivenoffice.nl/admin3/ckeditor/test1.html)

Comment: Where's your code? See [ask].

Comment: Link agiain

http://duivenoffice.nl/admin3/elFinder-2.1.20/testcode.txt




Hope someone help me to solved this

Comment: Sorry , I do not understand what you mean.

I work arround 3 days to solve my issue...can i give my email adres

Comment: Nobody who can helps me to work Elfinder with Ckeditor?